# Proof that no σ-complete non-principal filter on a countable set can exist

Tags: elementary-set-theory, filters

Jech (3rd edition, page 73) defines a principal filter as {X : Xo ⊆ X} with Xo a non empty subset of S and (page 77) indicates that there is no non-principal σ-complete (i.e. ω1 complete) filter on a countable set S, but provides no proof, so I was hoping that someone would be able to provide a reference to its proof.

I have seen a principal filter defined differently - with Xo being replaced by a single element of S. In this case if S is ω and the filter is ultra, it can't contain any finite subsets of ω. The filter must therefore contain all co-finite subsets of ω and therefore all end segments of ω, whose countable intersection is the empty set. So there is no non-principal σ-complete (ie ω1 complete) ultra-filter on ω.

As Jech strengthens the definition of "principal" from a single element of S to a subset Xo of S, it looks like the ultra-filter requirement (which ensures that any finite subset of S in an ultra-filter is always associated with a single element of S being in the ultra-filter) could be dropped, which Jech statement above suggests is the case.

Using Jech principal filter definition, an ω1 complete non-principal filter on ω must have > |ω| elements, as otherwise it would be principal. But I can't see how this ensures there is always an empty intersection of a countable number of elements in the filter, without getting into Continuum Hypothesis territory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a set is countable we can write it as $A=\{a_n\mid n<\omega\}$. If $U$ is a non-principal filter on $A$, then for some $n$'s, $A\setminus\{a_n\}\in U$. Look at $B=\bigcap\{A\setminus\{a_n\}\mid A\setminus\{a_n\}\in U\}$

Now apply $\sigma$-closure and examine what happens when $B\in U$.

Comment: Asaf, the filter in the question above isn't an ultra-filter - I have filled in the result for an ultra-filter in the question.  Is there some way your response can be extended to a filter, with Jech definition of principal ? Many thanks.

Comment: Ah, you are right. But the idea works without assuming the ultra-ness of the filter. Just takes one more step.

Comment: Asaf, if the filter isn't an ultra-filter the first step in your response can't be applied, so it can't be guaranteed that all co-finite sets are in the filter (unless you know of a reason why they should be). The filter can't have finite sets, but this doesn't mean that their compliment is in the filter.  The filter could only contain non finite, non-cofinite sets, i.e. infinitely long subsets of ω, whose intersection is w long as well.

Comment: No, it can't. But it can be applied to *some* of them. And when you intersect all those you get a set. And can that set be in the filter?

Comment: Ah, and that's the key question - why should some elements in the filter (that's not an ultra-filter)  intersect to lead to a co-finte set and in particular all the co-finite sets that are end segments of ω ? That's what I couldn't work out.

Comment: Well, if $B\in U$, then there is a proper subset of $B$ also in $U$ or $B$ is empty, why would that be a contradiction?

Comment: Asaf, nice one, many thanks I've got it now with your updated text. If the filter is non-principal then each of the an's cant be common to all elements of the filter.  Take an element f without a particular an, and apply the filter super-set axiom to fill up all the other elements that arent in f, to create A \ {an}. This applies to all an, so their countable intersection is empty, which contradicts the  ω1 complete definition of the filter.